# How can I add many Listviews inside a Horizontal scrollview?

Tags: java, android, xml

I am trying to achieve this in android. Can somebody help me out [having a dynamic number of listview horizontally inside another view](https://i.stack.imgur.com/niiRv.png)?
Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It will be easy if you use a RecyclerView. Then you will be able to set gridLayoutmanager. GridLayoutManager has options to set spanCount and it will set the layout to the number of required spans or columns.

```
GridLayoutManager (Context context, 
                int spanCount, 
                int orientation, 
                boolean reverseLayout)
```

[GridLayoutManager Docs](https://developer.android.com/reference/kotlin/androidx/recyclerview/widget/GridLayoutManager)

There are many tutorials to find as well.
[Tutorials](https://www.vogella.com/tutorials/AndroidRecyclerView/article.html)